# How to find latest library version for a specific Java version

Tags: java, maven, javassist

I have an app written in **Java version 6** (**an old project, no source code, no way to update**) and I want to add [Javassist](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist) library but the problem is that I don't know which version is compatible with Java 6, I couldn't find out any info about supported java version anywhere, seems like developers only include notes in the newest releases. Is there a way to find the latest compatible version?

Comment: why would you want to write code in such an old version? if you're starting a new project, it's better to update the java version

Comment: It was too hard to use google to find the home of javassis ? http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/ ? Took me 20 seconds ? Sorry..

Comment: I forgot to mention that's it's old project and there is no way to update java.

Comment: If there's no documentation, just try it out. Using binary search you should quickly find the latest version supporting Java 6.

Comment: *"... it's old project and there is no way to update java"*.  If you have source code, there is a way.  99.9% of Java 6 apps will run on a more recent version of Java with zero to minimal change.

Comment: @khmarbaise Seriously you assume that I can't find their home page? I couldn't find anything about supported version on their web page. I guess you even haven't read completly the question.

Comment: @StephenC I would love to update the app to java 8 but unfortunatelly I don't have the soruce code and also corporate restrictions come into play.

Comment: So why are you trying to incorporate Javassist into it?  The application is (at least) 4.5 years out of date.  Doing byte-code manipulation tricks on ancient application that you don't have source code for, and that only runs on an EOL'd Java platform is digging yourself deeper into a deep hole.  You / your management should be looking for an alternative to this app.

Comment: The sources could be reverse engineered. The build structure doable. After a first rebuild you are free: SonarLint/SpotBugs, newer java versions.

Comment: @MichaelDz Sorry but you haven't read the [release pages which contains information about that](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases). Based on that `3.18.2-GA`seemed to be the last which supports JDK 6..the next needs JDK 8 if I correctly understand the page apart from that you can take a deeper look into the commits...Furthermore a look into their poms shows that the code should work with JDK 6 also with the most recent version only the test code is made with Jdk 9 ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I have read releases page but haven't thought about looking into poms. That's the solution I was looking for, thanks for help anyway. Next time try to be more understanding, let's not ruin this great community.

Comment: @MichaelDz No problem.

Answer (score 1):

This guesswork, but bear with me.

1. The last public release of Java 6 was Java SE 6 Update 45 on 2013-04-16.
2. Javassist rel_3_18_2_ga was tagged / released on May 28, 2014.

If we assume that the Javassist didn't drop support for Java 6 in a patch release (which seems perverse), then rel_3_18_2_ga or even rel_3_18_3_ga *should be* compatible with Java 6 (still).

---

However, there are hints in the project's [Readme.html file](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/blob/master/Readme.html) that the current version of Javassist should be compatible with JDK 1.4 or later.  (You may need to build the Javassist JAR for yourself with an appropriate target version ...)

---

(But as per my comments above, I think this is the wrong approach.)